# Can not Insert into Database with SqlDataAdapter and MSSqlServer in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, dataadapter

I want to insert new record into the DataTable with DataAdapter. 
There are 2 columns in Person table. FirstName and LastName.
I have a code like below.

```
SqlConnection connection;
DataSet dsPerson;
SqlDataAdapter adapter;
string connectionString = Properties.Resources.ConnectionString;
connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

dsPerson = new DataSet("PersonDataSet");
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Person", connection);
adapter.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
adapter.Fill(dsPerson, "Person");

string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Person(FirstName, LastName) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)";
SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);

insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
insertCommand.Parameters["@FirstName"].SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
insertCommand.Parameters["@FirstName"].SourceColumn = "FirstName";

insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar));
insertCommand.Parameters["@LastName"].SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;
insertCommand.Parameters["@LastName"].SourceColumn = "LastName";

adapter.InsertCommand = insertCommand;
```

But when I try to insert new Record into DataSet it appears in the DataSet. But it does not do insert new record into DataBase.
The Code for Insert is below.

```
connection.Open();
DataRow newRow = dsPerson.Tables["Person"].NewRow();
newRow["FirstName"] = "Joseph";
newRow["LastName"] = "Sword";
dsPerson.Tables["Person"].Rows.Add(newRow);
dsPerson.Tables["Person"].AcceptChanges();
dsPerson.AcceptChanges();
adapter.Update(dsPerson, "Person");
connection.Close();
```

I even try to trace queries sent to sql server With Express Profiler. And i saw that it does not send insert command to the database.
So what is the problem? How to solve it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not call `AcceptChanges` methods of dataset and DataTable because `DataAdapter.Update` method affects only changed/added/deleted rows from datatable.

But after calling AcceptChanges all your DataRows will have `Unchanged` state.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference about DataAdapter:

> When an application calls the Update method, the DataAdapter examines
>   the RowState property, and executes the required INSERT, UPDATE, or
>   DELETE statements iteratively for each row, based on the order of the
>   indexes configured in the DataSet.